# Displaying View: Dropdown in LVWP Toolbar

Tags: list, list-view, xslt-list-view-web-part

So I'm trying to figure out why when I go into a specific list on the right side I have the "View" Dropdown, but when I am on a page with a List view web part with Show Toolbar it does not have the View Dropdown. I know that you can use the breadcrumb but this is not the solution I need. When you open the page in SPD the view drop down is visible in the list view web part, I cant seem to find a tag that is hiding it on the page. I know this was done intentionaly because of the breadcrumb, but there has to be a way to display it on the Toolbar as it appears in SPD. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Views is not an option for list view web parts placed on web part pages. It is defined in the web part settings when dropping it in a web part zone. This has been the case since 2007 if not earlier.